# Как определить, что сайт запущен как PWA?

Tags: javascript, frontend, pwa

У сайта есть PWA версия (и TWA). И необходимо собственноручно рекомендовать к загрузке TWA версию из playmarket (разумеется только в том случае, если сайт уже не запущен через TWA). так вот никак не могу найти способ определения этого. Вероятно нужно, как-то это делать через serviceWorker